# scroll to the bottom of the content if some content has been added to the `div`

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div and want it to scroll to the bottom of the content if some content has been added to the `div`.

This div has content dynamically added to it and needs to stay scrolled all the way down. Now if the user decides to scroll up, then if new content is added I want it to jump back to the bottom whatever the current position of the scroll bar, it shouldn't wait for the user to scrolls all the way down again, like in most chat applications.

How would I go about creating this? I have tried the below code but it doesn't seem to be working.

```js
let tempCounter = 0;
var msgdiv = document.getElementById("messages");

function addContent() {
  msgdiv.innerHTML +=
    "Long long content " + tempCounter++ + "!<br/>";

/***
  msgdiv.scrollTop = msgdiv.scrollHeight - msgdiv.clientHeight;
  ***/
  
  msgdiv.scrollTop = msgdiv.scrollHeight;


}

setInterval(function() {
  addContent();

}, 500)
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.mh-100 {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.chat-messages {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.bg-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.chat-messages-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <div class="chat-messages bg-white">
    <div class="chat-messages-text" id="messages">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-input bg-warning ">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="inputs" rows="3"></textarea>
    <button type="button" onclick="addContent()" class="btn btn-primary mb-2"> Send Message </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

```
msgdiv.scrollIntoView(false);
```

it will keep the scroll view at the bottom of the element. (true would keep it at the top.)

Comment: this seems to be working..but isn't there any caveat with this solution? just asking if you know any?

Comment: @aakashbahyal I too thought there were some caveats, in particular that Safari didn’t support it, but I’ve tested on Safari IOS and it is OK. I’ll test on other browsers. It isn’t supported on IE I think. Let me know if you find a problem and I’ll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) API to detect changes for your div, then you can trigger the scrolling to bottom

Comment: This is an interesting function, but in this case the problem is how to do the scrolling, the code already knows when new content is added.